# Python dictionnary items() method cost inside iterable

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable

I have not been benchmarking for now and I am wondering about the cost of items() (or keys() or values()) method of a dictionnary within an iterable. Let me explain :

I have 2 dictionnaries (of course, my real dicts are much longer):

```
One = {'a': 'dontmind', 'b': 'dontmind', 'c': 'whatever'}
Two = {'a': 'dontmind', 'c': 'dontmind'}
```

I want to check if all keys of "Two" are in "One" and would do it like this :

```
if all([key in One.keys() for key in Two.keys()]) :
    # do stuff!
```

I want to know if this way is better, considering performance :

```
one_keys = One.keys()
two_keys = Two.keys()
if all([key in one_keys for key in two_keys]) :
    # do stuff!
```

In this case, the keys() method is just called once for each dict. I don't really know about the underlying process of extracting keys from a dict, and whether the difference between these two ways is really significative. Can you help me?

Also, should I consider this way?

```
one_keys = One.keys()
two_keys = Two.keys()
for key in two_keys :
  if key not in one_keys :
    break
else :
  # do stuff!
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Python 2.x, `.keys()` returns a list, so calling that multiple times is a bit of an overhead... In 3.x, it returns a `dict_keys` object which has `set`-like behaviour, so the simplest for 3.x would be:

```
contains_all = two.keys() <= one.keys()
```

The equivalent in Python 2.7 is `viewkeys`:

```
contains_all = two.viewkeys() <= one.viewkeys()
```

For earlier versions, convert `two` to a set and check it's a subset of `one`, eg:

```
contains_all = set(two).issubset(one)
```

**Python 3.x timings**:

```
%timeit two.keys() <= one.keys()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 557 ns per loop
%timeit set(two).issubset(one)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 732 ns per loop
%timeit all(key in one for key in two)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 µs per loop
```

**Python 2.7 timings (to show `.viewkeys()`)**:

```
%timeit two.viewkeys() <= one.viewkeys()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 484 ns per loop
%timeit set(two).issubset(one)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 677 ns per loop
%timeit all(key in one for key in two)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is '<= ' an operator on list to check if all elements of one are in the other? Or is it a length comparison? (maybe stupid question)

Comment: `<=` in this instance is operating on `set`-like objects (`dict_keys`) and it's equivalent to `set.issubset` - which checks that all keys present on the left are present on the right

Answer (score 1):

For the best performance in both 2.7 (but not earlier versions) and 3.x, I would recommend writing this:

```
if all(key in One for key in Two):
    # do stuff!
```

This avoids several pitfalls:

- Generator expressions do not pull the entire sequence into memory, the way list comprehensions do.
- In 2.x, `.keys()` returns a list.  Testing membership of a list is slow, but testing membership of a dictionary is fast.  In 3.x, `.keys()` returns a set-like object, so this is not a problem there.
- Furthermore, that list takes up extra space, which we're saving under 2.7.  3.x's set-like `.keys()` is a "view" of the existing dictionary, so again this is not a problem under 3.x.

Comment: Thank your for this quick answer! I will try this. I plan to do some benchmarking, i'll let you know about this if you want.

Comment: @jean.stache: Remember that when we talk about speed, we're usually focused on *scalability* rather than absolute timing.  A dictionary is "faster" than two lists with corresponding indices because the dictionary can reasonably scale to hundreds or thousands of entries, while the lists will become too slow as they get big.  If you're testing small examples, you may not see much difference, or even get the opposite results.